# Create a function to be called multiple times in multiple methods

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, methods, vuejs2

Hello and happy new year everyone! I need a hand with a procedure that I repeat several times in multiple methods, please. I'll write you an example in short:

```
method1() {
  //I DO THINGS

  const controlArray = []; 
  this.daySelected.forEach((element) => {
    
    const tStart = element.time.map((t) => t.startIsGreater); 

    if (tStart.includes(true)) {
      
      controlArray.push(tStart); 
      this.setNewEventInfoRequired(false); 
      this.setAlertWarning(true); 
    }
  });
},

method2() {
  //I DO OTHER THINGS DIFFERENT FROM THE FIRST METHOD

  const controlArray = []; 
  this.daySelected.forEach((element) => {
    

    const tStart = element.time.map((t) => t.startIsGreater); 

    if (tStart.includes(true)) {
      controlArray.push(tStart); 
      this.setNewEventInfoRequired(false); 
      this.setAlertWarning(true); 
    }
  });
},
 // and then I repeat the same with other methods (methodFoo, methodBar, etc...)
```

Everything I write from const controlArray to the end, I repeat the same in multiple methods, so how do I put all that piece of code in one function and just call that function in the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that common code in one method then call it in every method:

```
runCommonFunc(){ // give it a significative name
     const controlArray = []; 
  this.daySelected.forEach((element) => {
    

    const tStart = element.time.map((t) => t.startIsGreater); 

    if (tStart.includes(true)) {
      controlArray.push(tStart); 
      this.setNewEventInfoRequired(false); 
      this.setAlertWarning(true); 
    }
  });
},

method1(){
//I do things
this.runCommonFunc()
},

method21(){
//I do things
this.runCommonFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method that you will use the same functionality and then call this method inside to other methods.

Here I created the `helperMethod` which is called to `method1` and `method2`.

```
helperMethod(){
 const controlArray = []; //creo un array che conterrà elementi true
  this.daySelected.forEach((element) => {
    //per ogni elemento all'interno dell'array principale daySelected

    const tStart = element.time.map((t) => t.startIsGreater); //mappo l'elemento che contiene la proprietà startIsGreater

    if (tStart.includes(true)) {
      //se l'elemento mappato contiene true
      controlArray.push(tStart); //lo inserisco dentro l'array di controllo
      this.setNewEventInfoRequired(false); //il pulsante create scompare
      this.setAlertWarning(true); //l'alert appare
    }
  });
},
method1(){
this.helperMethod();
},
method2(){
this.helperMethod();
}
```